# Mean residual life with censored observations and covariant eps

Tags: r, regression, survival

I have a time variable ( time of claim settlement after occurrence ) that may be censored ( claim still open at the moment of observation) and some additional covariates ( line of business, claim size, ...) I am interested to estimate the mean residual life for claims still open. My question is twofold :
1. If I do not want to use covariates exists any approach to estimate the mean residual time unbiased way ( and an R package (?
2. Is there an approach and corresponding R package to perform such estimation allowing for covariates effect ?

Comment: what are "eps"?

Comment: sorry I meant covariates

Comment: Hi, maybe you can use R package “flexsurv” to run your survival regression.  Then you can use “reslife” package to find the MRL.  Disclaimer: I helped create the “reslife” package.